# Printing email messages from mutt -- how to avoid line break?

Tags: email, printing, mutt

I use mutt as email client, and recently decided to fix my email-printing setup.

I know about Muttprint, but I decided not to use it. I came up with the following.

On `.muttrc`, I have:

```
set print_command="grep -v X-Spam-Status | $HOME/bin/mutt_print.sh"
```

The `~/bin/mutt_print.sh` script, which I adapted from stuff I found on the net, is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PDIR="$HOME/tmp/mutt_print" 
OPEN_PDF=zathura

# create temp dir if it does not exist
if [ ! -d "$PDIR" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$PDIR" 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Unable to make directory '$PDIR'" 1>&2
        exit 2
    fi
fi

infile="`mktemp $PDIR/mutt_XXXXXXXX.txt`"
tmpfile="`mktemp $PDIR/mutt_XXXXXXXX.ps`"
outfile="`mktemp $PDIR/mutt_XXXXXXXX.pdf`"

echo "infile = $infile"
echo "tmpfile = $tmpfile"
echo "outfile = $outfile"

while read line
do
  echo "$line" >> $infile
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"

echo "running vim $infile -c \"hardcopy > $outfile | q\""
vim $infile -c "hardcopy > $tmpfile | q"
echo "running ps2pdf $tmpfile $outfile"
ps2pdf $tmpfile $outfile

read
$OPEN_PDF $outfile >/dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 1
rm $infile $tmpfile $outfile
```

So, when I decide to print a message, Mutt opens it with Zathura, and I can either print it or save the PDF -- this is the setup I want.

However, I noticed that although I used `grep` to remove the `X-Spam-Status` line, it does not always work: sometimes the like seems to be broken before it is sent to the print command, and part of it is displayed in the PDF:

```
Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 21:17:14 −0300
From: John Doe <john.doe@somewhereoutthere.com>
To: my-email@here
Subject: Re: blah
tests=FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_MESSAGE,RDNS_NONE,T_DKIM_INVALID
```

The `X-Spam-Status` line inthe original message was

```
X-Spam-Status: No, hits=2.4 required=8.0 tests=FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_MESSAGE,RDNS_NONE,T_DKIM_INVALID
```

which is broken between `required=8.0` and `tests...`.

So -- how can I avoid the breaking of that line?

(I also welcome any suggestions of improvement to the script)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like that `X-Spam-Status` line is a 'continued' RFC822 header that spans multiple lines.

A header starts with non-whitespace in the first character of a line.  A non-blank line with whitespace at the beginning is a continuation of the previous line, and a blank line ends the headers.

If you want to filter out a particular header, you are going to need something more RFC822 aware than `grep`.  Perhaps a `perl` or `awk` thing.

You might even do something about it in that

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line" >> $infile
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

like not echo a line that begins with a `X-Spam-Status` (and set a flag), then skip 'continued' lines until you hit a new header (and clear the flag).

Either way it takes program awareness of how RFC822 headers are formatted.

Maybe you need to ask yourself if you really care about that header so much in your printout

Still, a filter isn't that hard

```
#!/user/bin/perl

my $skip=0;

# First do the headers
while(<STDIN>)
{
        #Test for end of headers
        if(/^\s*$/)
        {
                #copy the header ending blank
                printf $_;

                #exit the while loop
                last;
        }

        #Starts with non whitespace, new header
        $skip = 0 if /^\S/;

        #skip stuff if its the header we don't want
        $skip = 1 if /^X-Spam-Status/i;

        #copy lines if we're not skipping
        print $_ if !$skip;
}

# now the rest of the file
while(<STDIN>)
{
        #copy lines
        print $_;
}
```

Comment: @jay just added a perl script you can use in place of the `grep -v`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still don't get one thing: in the original message, the X-Spam-Status line shows up as a single line. It seems that Mutt breaks it in order to print the message (makes sense...)

Comment: Perhaps it sees printing as a sort of 'send'.  If so, it does wrap headers at sending per this option.  https://dev.mutt.org/doc/manual.html#wrap-headers

Answer (score 2):

As @infixed says, the X-Spam-Status header is continued across multiple lines.

If you have `procmail` installed, you can use its `formail` utility to concatenate continued headers.

From `man formail`:

> -c      Concatenate continued fields in the header.  Might  be  convenient
>   when postprocessing mail with standard (line oriented) text utilities.

For example:

```
set print_command="formail -c | grep -v X-Spam-Status: | $HOME/bin/mutt_print.sh"
```

Even better, you can use `formail -I` to remove a header, without the need for `grep -v`:

```
set print_command="formail -I X-Spam-Status | $HOME/bin/mutt_print.sh"
```

> -I headerfield
>
> Same as -i, except that any existing  similar  fields  are  simply removed.   If headerfield consists only of a field-name, it effectively deletes the field.

---

RE: improvements to the script:

1. Why use vim (and [hardcopy](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Print_to_a_Postscript_file)) when tools like `a2ps` and `enscript` exist?

   Both of those have all sorts of useful options for formatting text and the postscript output.
2. Why the slow `while read line...` loop when you could just use `cat ${1:--} > "$infile"` to save stdin to a file?
3. Always put double-quotes around your variables when you use them. e.g. don't use `$infile`, use `"$infile"` instead.
4. Use $(...) rather than back-ticks.
5. The script doesn't use any bash-specific features, so use `#!/bin/sh` (or maybe `#!/bin/dash` if you have it installed).
6. If you're using `mkdir -p`, you don't need to test if the directory already exists.  `mkdir -p` does that for you already.
7. `gjots2lpr` from the [gjots2](http://bhepple.freeshell.org/gjots/) package seems to do most or all of what your script does.

   Your script could be replaced with a simple wrapper around `gjots2lpr` that sets the environment variables it uses to override the defaults (e.g. to tell it whether to use `a2ps` or `enscript`, what ps/pdf viewer to use, what print command to use, etc).

   From `gjots2lpr -h`:

> Usage: gjots2lpr [-pt ] [ filename ... ]
>
> Prints a text file - if possible using postscript or PDF and available
>   pre-viewers and printer dialog. It looks for and uses whatever
>   utilities it can find on the system.
>
> If 'filename' is not given then STDIN is printed.